# Magus Maneuvers

Tags: pathfinder-1e, touch-attacks, magus

Researched and valid [magus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus) maneuver:

- Cast Touch Spell -> 5 foot step -> Spellstrike with no concentration check

Is this valid:

- Cast Touch Spell -> Move action -> Spellstrike with no concentration check?

And is there any way I can use a 5 foot step or a move action to avoid casting defensively with a spell combat/spellstrike combo?
Merci!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, cast then move then spellstrike is legal, just like a normal wizard casting a touch spell, moving, and then using a free action to deliver it is legal. In fact, this exact scenario is addressed in the [FAQ/Errata sidebar on the Magus page on d20pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus) and is derived from a [Paizo blog FAQ posting on the subject](http://paizo.com/paizo/blog/v5748dyo5ld3d?FAQ-Attack).

And sure, just like any other situation, if you aren't threatened when you cast you don't have to cast defensively, so as long as that 5' or move action moves you from a nonthreatened area, no concentration check is required.